# Regular Expression (VB.NET)

Tags: regex, vb.net

How I can convert this:

```
, ...Name: John, LastName: Smith, Gender: Male, ...
```

into

```
, ...Name: John, Gender: Male, ...
```

Notice I replace " LastName: XXXXX," by "" (empty chain)

I've tried with

```
'Remove LastName...
pattern = " LastName.*,"
replacement = ","
msAccessQuery = Regex.Replace(string, pattern, replacement)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pattern will be:

```
 \s*LastName:[^,]*,
```